# In csproj, can I conditionally include a file based on runtime identifier?

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

Suppose I build my project these ways.

```
dotnet publish -r win-x86
dotnet publish -r linux-musl-x64
```

Is there a way in my `.csproj` file to automatically include a native DLL based on the chosen [RID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)?

Answer (score 12):

You just need a `Condition` on the element you want to control in the csproj file. For example:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyLibrary.Linux" Version="1.0.0" 
    Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)'=='linux-x64'" />

<PackageReference Include="MyLibrary.Windows" Version="1.0.0" 
    Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)'=='win-x64'" />
```

Comment: perhaps you have a complete code example ? I can't make it work. There's no #if RID available. And if I define them it's not cleat how to set a value there. In case of #if NET 6 and so on all is clear but it does not in case of RIDs